# Passing SQL Results in labels

Tags: actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I have a select statement that queries the top 5 players who got high scores

```
selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;            
selectStmt.text="SELECT name, level, score FROM highscores WHERE ROWID <=5 ORDER BY score DESC";        
selectStmt.execute();
```

I want the name, level, and score displayed in labels. How can I pass the results in labels?

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Listen `SQLEvent.RESULT`
2. Execute your query
3. Process the result

```
selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
selectStmt.text="SELECT name, level, score FROM highscores WHERE ROWID <=5 ORDER BY score DESC";

// Create a listener in order to process the results
var resultHandler:Function = function(event:SQLEvent):void {
    selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);

    // Get the result
    var result:SQLResult = dbStatement.getResult();
    if (result != null) {
        // Iterate through each entries
        for each (var entry:Object in result.data) {
            // Trace entry
            trace(entry.name, entry.level, entry.score);
        }
    }
};

// Add a listener in order to read the results when the request will be done
selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
selectStmt.execute();
```

Comment: How can I pass the results in the label component? The code just trace the results.

Comment: txt1.text=result.data[0].name; worked but when I delete all the records in table I got an Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.